# Change Thule foot pack clamp kit

Tags: troubleshooting

I have a Thule Evo clamp foot pack with a clamp kit for my car. I would like to put this onto another vehicle. It looks like I just need to change the clamp kit (and can reuse the foot pack), but I’m not sure how to remove the existing clamps form the foot pack.

Any ideas? When setting it up initially they just “click in”.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you have any photos of the parts in question? That might help us to see

Comment: Read the instructions - "click-in" could mean removable later or "clicked-in" forever...

Answer (score 1):

yes it comes out pretty easily....lever it....push down from the Thuele label when you have it on a table and it pops right out